# How to pass argument or value while running newman from gitlab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, newman, postman-collection

i'm new using postman to automate some API. I setup newman to run my collections in gitlab pipeline. I wanted to allow the user to set a value for a Gitlab variables before running my newman test pipeline. i added to my gitlab-ci this command line:

```
 script:
    - newman --version
    - newman run PalmyraStudio.postman_collection.json -e env.json -g variables.json --env-var "apversion=$APP_VERSION" --insecure
```

then i added to the environment variables this section to define the var appversion:

```
{
        "key": "appversion",
        "value": "$APP_VERSION",
        "enabled": true
    }
```

on the request body i called the variable "appversion" then i runned the pipeline with setting the variable value so it failed because the variable appversion is unknown

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here but in your `script:` it reads `apversion` (missing one "p")…

Comment: @slauth
yes thank you it works fine but have you idea how to pass more than one parameter for --env-var "" ?

thanks

Comment: Just specify it multiple times… `--env-var "appversion=$APP_VERSION" --env-var "foo=bar"`